# How to run a cron task at the last minute of each day?

Tags: cron, node-cron

Is this the correct way to run a cron task at the last minute of each day? This is to be used on [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

```
* 59 23 * * *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your Cron expression means, every second, at 59 minutes past the hour, between 11:00 PM and 11:59 PM

```
59 23 * * *
```

Above is the one you are looking for.This means Every day At 11:59 PM